# Polymer App more than 1 landpage

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit, firebase-polymer

Hi guys I'm currently work in a new project. Basically I'm trying to build an app with more then 1 landpage.

[image]

[image]

I choose iron-pages to show which page to display. I create 2 custom components  and . By now it is only h2 tag.

[https://github.com/jeandersoncruz/my-app]

Question: Is this the correct architecture? Why is not the elements render in page?

https://my-app-e6032.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your architecture, as far as I can tell.

Maybe check versions on your dependencies?

Here is a working snippet for reference using today's (3/22/2017) versions (wc 1.0.0-rc.6, shady 1.0.0-rc.2, polymer 2.0.0-rc.3, iron 2.0-preview).

When Polymer 2.0 is final (imminent) the version numbers will stabilize.

```html
  <base href="//polygit.org/webcomponentsjs+webcomponents+v1.0.0-rc.6/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0-rc.2/polymer+v2.0.0-rc.3/iron*+polymerelements+:2.0-preview/components/"></script>
  
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
  
  <shell-app></shell-app>
  
  <dom-module id="landpage-1">
    <template>
      <h2>Hello [[prop1]]</h2>
    </template>
    <script>
      class Mylandpage1 extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'landpage-1'; }
        static get properties() {
          return {
            prop1: {
              type: String,
              value: 'landpage-1'
            }
          };
        }
      }
      window.customElements.define(Mylandpage1.is, Mylandpage1);
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="shell-app">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }
      </style>
      <iron-pages selected="0">
        <div><landpage-1></landpage-1></div>
        <div><landpage-1></landpage-1></div>
      </iron-pages>
    </template>
    <script>
      class MyApplication extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'shell-app'; }
        static get properties() {
          return {
            prop1: {
              type: String,
              value: 'shell-app'
            }
          };
        }
      }
      window.customElements.define(MyApplication.is, MyApplication);
    </script>
  </dom-module>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, I appreciate.